# Is there a built-in function to split a 3-channel Mat into three 3-channel Mat rather than into three 1-channel Mat?

Tags: opencv

As far as I know the built-in `split` will split one 3-channel `Mat` into three 1-channel `Mat`. As a result, those three `Mat` are just gray scale with some different intensities.

My intent is to get three 3-channel `Mat` as follows.

```
void splitTo8UC3(const Mat& input, vector<Mat>& output)
{
    Mat blue = input.clone();
    Mat green = input.clone();
    Mat red = input.clone();
    const uint N = input.rows * input.step;

    for (uint i = 0; i < N; i += 3)
    {
        // blue.data[i]
        green.data[i] = 0;
        red.data[i] = 0;


        blue.data[i + 1] = 0;
        //green.data[i+1]
        red.data[i + 1] = 0;


        blue.data[i + 2] = 0;
        green.data[i + 2] = 0;
        //red.data[i+2]
    }

    output.push_back(blue);
    output.push_back(green);
    output.push_back(red);
}
```

It works but instead of reinventing the wheel, I am looking for the built-in if any.

## Edit

The proposed solution must be faster than mine.

Comment: emm use default split to 3  1-channel mat then use cvtcolor?

Comment: @DrYuanShenghai You get three `CV_U8C1`, so grayscale images. Using `cvtColor` will then lead to "gray" `CV_U8C3`, i.e. the color information in each channel is the same, which is not, what OP wants - as I can tell.

Comment: oh i get it.  The same split 3 1-channel. THen use Merge with newly created 2X cv::Mat with all 0 input to form the new 3-channel

Comment: @DrYuanShenghai I tested this approach using the code provided by the OP in his comment to my answer, and using `cv::merge` is also slower than his original solution, which might come from the fact, that `cv::merge` is stated as a "partial case" of `cv::mixChannels`. Direct manipulating the single pixels seems to be the fastest so far. @MoneyOrientedProgrammer Maybe, you should add the constraint to be faster than your solution to your question. My first impression was, you (just) want to have a simpler/cleaner/better-to-read code. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDIT:** I incorporated Dan's suggested improvements from his comment.

---

I can't think of a built-in function exactly doing this, and I also couldn't find one. But while doing some research, I came across the [`mixChannels`](https://docs.opencv.org/4.1.0/d2/de8/group__core__array.html#ga51d768c270a1cdd3497255017c4504be) function, which might improve your solution. At least, it avoids implementing a loop.

Here are my modifications to your code:

```cpp
void splitTo8UC3(const cv::Mat& input, std::vector<cv::Mat>& output)
{
    // Allocate outputs
    cv::Mat b(cv::Mat::zeros(input.size(), input.type()));
    cv::Mat g(cv::Mat::zeros(input.size(), input.type()));
    cv::Mat r(cv::Mat::zeros(input.size(), input.type()));

    // Collect outputs
    cv::Mat out[] = { b, g, r };

    // Set up index pairs
    int from_to[] = { 0,0, 1,4, 2,8 };

    cv::mixChannels(&input, 1, out, 3, from_to, 3);
    output.assign(std::begin(out), std::end(out));
}
```

Let's have this test image `colors.png`:

[image]

And, let's have this test code:

```cpp
    cv::Mat img = cv::imread("images/colors.png");

    std::vector<cv::Mat> bgr;

    splitTo8UC3(img, bgr);

    cv::imwrite("images/b.png", bgr[0]);
    cv::imwrite("images/g.png", bgr[1]);
    cv::imwrite("images/r.png", bgr[2]);
```

Then, we get the following outputs `b.png`, `g.png`, and `r.png`, which hopefully are the them as for your initial solution:

[image]
[image]
[image]

Hope that helps!

Comment: @MoneyOrientedProgrammer Wow - then I don't want to know, what they're doing under the hood. Of course, then, keep your implementation!

Comment: Just a reference (that you might not be interested in): https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/50583102#50583102

Comment: Good idea. If you avoid copying zeros over zeros, and get rid of `k`, it will be faster than OP's code (See https://pastebin.com/ag7C1ZPK). The benchmark is also a little unfair, since OP's code only adds to the `output` vector (so at the end of the test it has 30 entries, instead of just 3), whereas you (IMHO correcly) assign the 3 channel `Mats` (and deallocate the old ones if present). Fixing that brings OP's code much closer to yours time-wise. Gotta run now.

Comment: @DanMašek: You are genius! Thanks!

Comment: @Dan How embarassing - you're totally right! I edited my answer and put in your improvements.

Comment: NO worries. [Some further ideas](https://pastebin.com/K09EbejL). You can simplify it a bit further if you skip `r`,`g`,`b` and populate `output` first. Then drop `out` and use `&output[0]` instead. Add some asserts to validate input. | Next step, make `from_to` a `std::vector<int>`. This then lets you make the function work for any number of channels (it already supports any depth). | Finally, you can add ability to reuse `output` if it's the correct type/shape -- just zeroing the `Mat`s instead of reallocation is noticeably faster.